# Does lastIndexOf work for googlescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I'm trying to find lastIndexOf for array received from my function numberCellToMerge().

```
  function numberCellToMerge(colName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var getDevSheet = ss.getSheetByName(colName); //colName is qual to sheet name
  var numberOfRowsToCheck = (findFirstEmptyRow(colName)-1);
  var columnTimePosition = (findTimeForDev(colName));
  var rangeTime = getDevSheet.getRange(2, columnTimePosition, numberOfRowsToCheck);
  var timeValues = rangeTime.getValues();
  return timeValues;
}
```

The timeValues returns array, for example [1,2,3,2,2,1,2,2].
And now I need to find lastIndexOf() this way:

```
function returnLastIndex() {    
var value = numberCellToMerge(devName);
var a = value.lastIndexOf(2);
var valueX = [1,2,3,2,2,1,2,2];
var b = valueX.lastIndexOf(2);
}
```

but I still receive -1 as a result, but b returns 7. Maybe it's because lastIndexOf will search for string and my array contains integers, but unfortunately I didn't found how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Clearly `lastIndexOf` works because the value of `b` is correct. So maybe `numberCellToMerge` isn't returning the data you're expecting.

Comment: How it's possible?
When I call for value by an index I receive it:

Comment: Yes, I knew, but how it's possible?
When I call for value by an index I receive it: var dd = value[7] it's return 2. For each index it works correct...
What could be wrong with this array then?